# Standard ML Binary Tree Traversal

Tags: binary-tree, sml, ml, tree-traversal

I am new to SML and doing a practice about tree traversal.
This is the setting of question.

```
datatype 'a bTree = nil | bt of 'a bTree * 'a * 'a bTree;
```

I need to write a function inorder which accepts a binary tree and return a lists of all members of the tree in inorder traversal.

I wrote this line:

```
fun inorder(nil) = nil
  | inorder(bt(left,key,right)) = inorder(left) @ [key] @ inorder(right);
```

But get some error and don't know how to fix:

```
Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
operator domain: 'Z list * 'Z list
operand:         'Z list * 'Y bTree
in expression:
  (key :: nil) @ inorder right

Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
operator domain: 'Z list * 'Z list
operand:         'Y bTree * _
in expression:
  inorder left @ (key :: nil) @ inorder right
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've inadvertently hidden the `nil` list constructor and replaced it with your tree constructor of the same name.

This means that your first case,

```
inorder(nil) = nil
```

says that the result of `inorder` is a tree; its type is

```
'a bTree -> 'a bTree
```

and you can't append (`@`) a list to a `'a bTree`.

Your code will work if you rename the empty tree constructor:

```
datatype 'a bTree = nilTree | bt of 'a bTree * 'a * 'a bTree;

fun inorder nilTree = nil
  | inorder (bt(left,key,right)) = inorder left @ [key] @ inorder right;
```

or use `[]` instead of `nil`.
Not hiding `nil` is the better solution, though.